# pytest run using threads causes future tests to fail

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading, testing, pytest

I have a `pytest` class that sets up a server in a separate thread before each tests via `setUp()` like this:

```
def setUp(self):
    host = "localhost"
    port = 13620
    scheme = "grpc+tcp"
    location = "{}://{}:{}".format(scheme, host, port)
    self.arrow_server = FlightServer(host, location)
    def start_server():
        pa.start(self.arrow_server)
    self.t = threading.Thread(target=start_server, args=(), daemon=True)
    self.t.start()
```

And in `tearDown()` I shut down the server and call `join()` on the thread:

```
def tearDown(self):
    self.arrow_server.shutdown()
    self.t.join()
    self.arrow_server = None
```

The tests behave and pass as expected, but in subsequent `pytest` invocations, other unrelated integration tests fail due to `ProcessLookupError: [Errno 3] No such process` in their `tearDown` method:

```
def tearDown(self):
    if self.process is not None:
        if platform.system() == "Windows":
            subprocess.call(["taskkill", "/F", "/T", "/PID", str(self.process.pid)])
        else:
            os.killpg(os.getpgid(self.process.pid), signal.SIGTERM)
        self.process.kill()
```

These tests fail invariably unless I restart my computer. This issue also occurs in Github Actions.

I'm guessing my code has some unintended side effects outside the context of `pytest`, but I'm not sure why or how.

Comment: where is `self.process` set, can you show that

Comment: It's set in the `setUp` phase of other tests in the suite.
`self.process = subprocess.Popen(cmd, preexec_fn=preexec_fn, stdout=outfile, stderr=outfile)`